# How to prevent git from automatically doing a binary diff on large files?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-diff, git-config

I've read online that once the files in a merge exceed a certain threshold, git automatically does a binary diff instead of a textual one. As a result, we lose the functionality of line-by-line resolution, even if the diff itself is quite small.

I have a ~1.3 GB CSV file that is supposed to represent a database, and it seems as if this is just over this large file threshold, according to this [link](https://public-inbox.org/git/CACsJy8CGQ4ynYFT0mY1DfcGGdzwP36eonMvr-kEZazX_82ag2Q@mail.gmail.com/T/). I'm currently trying to benchmark Git's conflict detection algorithm, so I would need the textual diff algorithm to run on this file.

Is there a way to increase the size threshold for automatically doing a binary diff instead of a textual one? I have already tried

```
git config --global --add core.bigFileThreshold 2g
```

but that seems not to help. I think it doesn't help because from what I understand, this only sets an upper bound on the size of file eligible for a textual diff, but having a file size less than `core.bigFileThreshold` doesn't guarantee it won't treat it as binary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As your link mentions, Git uses xdiff for text diffing, and

> that 1GB limit is a hard limit that the code can't cope with; our options are
> either to generate a binary diff or to die.

so the answer to

> Is there a way to increase the size threshold for automatically doing a binary diff instead of a textual one?

would seem to be "no."

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for the answer!